# Годы или года?

Tags: морфология

Расцвет пришёлся на 20-е и 30-е годы(а) 18 века.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Правильно: Расцвет пришёлся на 20-е и 30-е годы 18 века.

Формы "годы и года" различаются по смыслу и по стилю.
Смысловое различие можно определить по  толковому словарю:

1. Только годы, годов (с порядк. числ.). Промежуток времени в пределах десятилетия. Люди сороковых годов. Девяностые годы двадцатого века.
2. Годы и года, годов. Период времени, охватывающий некоторое количество лет. Школьные годы. Годы детства. В годы первой пятилетки. Лучшие годы.
3. Годы и года, годов. Возраст. Скрывать свои годы. Годы молодые. Годы преклонные. Не по годам одет.

Таким образом, мы видим, что только в значении 2 и 3 допускаются оба варианта, при этом основной (нейтральной) является форма "годы", а "года" употребляется в разговорной или поэтической речи (мои года, "у меня растут года").