# Форма "года" как множественное число

Tags: окончания, множественное-число

Задался тут вопросом, в каких случаях "года" как множественное число от слова "год" является основным вариантом, а не только разговорным. Нашёл [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32532/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) вопрос с ответом Софьи, в котором она пишет, что во 2-м и 3-м значении (из её ответа) «"года" употребляется в разговорной или поэтической речи».

Возникает вопрос: *в поэтической речи возможны **только года** для этих значений?*

Например, в песне поётся "мои года, моё богатство". Нельзя, кажется, сказать "мои годы" здесь, верно? То же верно и для других случаев, или есть примеры употребления слова "годы" в поэтической речи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут только вопрос ударения и размера. В слове "годы" ударение на первый слог, а в слове "года" на второй. Что лучше ложится на размер стиха - тем и пользуются.

Годы, годы мои,
Почему вы летите как птицы,
Будто очень боитесь куда-то на миг опоздать?
Что вас ждет впереди?
Так ли нужно туда торопиться?
Что вещает-пророчит далекая ваша звезда?
Я спешить не хочу. В сердце юность еще не отпела.
Я еще не успела свои переделать дела.
Не смогла отыскать то,
Что очень хотела,
Но я веры своей в чудеса не сожгла.
Я спешить не хочу.
Я еще улыбаться умею
Солнцу, ветрам, дождям и траве голубой.
Годы, годы мои,
Постареть, поумнеть я успею,
Но пока, вас прошу,
Вы меня не зовите с собой...

Автор неизвестен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за пример!

Comment: Так всё-таки в песне "мои годА" именно оттого, что ритмически иначе не получается, верно?

Comment: Д. Э. Розенталь отмечает, что слова гОды и годА относятся к стилистически разграничиваемым случаям. Форма на -ы(-и) свойственна книжной, преимущественно письменной речи, а форма на -а(-я) - устно-разговорной. На мой взгляд, выбор формы зависит от авторского замысла, а в примере, который Вы приводили еще и от размера стиха, как и писал Александр.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один пример употребления слова "годы" в поэтической речи.

Вот так и живём, не ждём тишины,
Мы юности нашей как прежде верны.
А сердце, как прежде, горит оттого,
Горит оттого,
Что дружба превыше всего.

А *годы* летят, наши *годы* как птицы летят,
И некогда нам оглянуться назад.

Comment: Спасибо, Стася!